# Configurar librería SOIL para OpenGL (C++) con WinGW en Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Intento aprender a programar en C++, voy por la mitad del libro *Programming principles and practice using C++*, por lo que decidí aventurarme con gráficos OpenGL siguiendo el libro *OpenGL game development by example*, sin embargo y contrario a lo recomendado de utilizar en entorno de Visual C++, pretendo seguir con mi entorno de preferencia Visual Studio Code.

Ahora bien, para configurar C++ en Visual Studio Code seguí la guía de instalación oficial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw, lo que deja habilitado MinGW (gcc, g++, gbd)

Luego configure OpenGL para trabajar con Visual Studio Code, siguiendo el video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd296_UQCzM, que descarga GLFW para crear ventanas y GLEW como wrangler, lo más interesante es que crea un script Python para lidiar con el proceso de compilación de C++.

```
import subprocess
file_name = "main"
include_dir = "dependencies/include"
lib_dir = "dependencies/lib"
lib = "-lglfw3 -lglew32s -lopengl32 -lgdi32"
preprocessor = "-DGLEW_STATIC"
 
def main():
    subprocess. Call(f"g++ {preprocessor} -c main.cpp -I{include_dir}")
    subprocess.call(f"g++ {preprocessor} *.o -o {file_name} -L{lib_dir} {lib}")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Lo que me facilita mucho el trabajo. Hasta aquí tengo correctamente configurado C++ y OpenGL en Visual Studio Code.

El problema surge cuando en el libro con que aprendo OpenGL me pide utilizar la librería para OpenGL llamada SOIL (Simple OpenGL Image Library) dado que en ella se lidia con la carga de texturas de imágenes de forma sencilla, hasta ahora solo puedo cargar .bmp sin utilizar librería, por lo que lo primero que hice fue descargar SOIL de una copia de la página lonesock.net/soil.html, sin embargo, el proceso de instalación de SOIL (generar la librería estática) se presenta para sistema Linux (utilizando make) y sistema Windows (Utilizando Visual Studio), y no presenta ninguna solución para Visual Studio Code (MinGW), dado que las librerías estáticas generadas tanto para el sistema Linux como para el entorno Visual Studio no sirven, me es imposible configurar SOIL en mi actual espacio de trabajo. SOIL también puede encontrarse en https://github.com/littlstar/soil

Segundo intento con SOIL2 https://github.com/SpartanJ/soil2, y el problema aquí que sigue la guía de instalación es que después de usar premake5, al utilizar make (que instale desde chocolatey), necesito tener instalado SDL2 para generar un archivo estático correcto, así que ahora solo tenía que instalar SDL2 en el espacio configurado para generar la librería estática.

```
"==== Building soil2-static-lib (debug_x86_64) ===="
"==== Building soil2-shared-lib (debug_x86_64) ===="
"==== Building soil2-test (debug_x86_64) ===="
"test_SOIL2.cpp"
../../src/test/test_SOIL2.cpp:15:18: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
   15  |    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
   |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Lo que me ha resultado en una tarea imposible, intente descargando https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.28.5 y utilizando los archivos del release devel MinGW, los intento ubicar en el proyecto SOIL2 en diferentes ubicaciones, con él .dll, pero no logro establecer como configurar SDL2 en ese espacio.

Si alguno pudiera compartir un template utilizando SOIL o SOIL2 junto a OpenGL en Visual Studio Code, sería un salvavidas, o me indicara como generar correctamente los archivos para instalar y configurar la libreria en el espacio de trabajo.

Gracias por la atención prestada, espero alguno pueda iluminarme.

Comment: SDL lo necesita para los tests. Yo creo que ya debería haber generado la librería. También te sugiero ver estos videos para aprender opengl https://youtube.com/@VictorGordan

Comment: Genera la librería, pero al utilizarla no parece funcionar correctamente (no bota error al compilar con ella, pero carga con 0 información la textura), supongo que por no tener SDL2 instalado, no lo se.

Comment: Claro. SDL es otra librería de creación de ventanas como GLFW y tiene muchas más funciones.